# Selecting recent posts in two different tables (SQL)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, join

I have two tables, Expense and EditedExpense. I have these two tables because when you want to edit a post in Expense, it creates a new post in EditedExpense. So you have always the original post in Expense table. You can only change the original post (expense table). If you change an Expnese three times, you will find three EditedExpense with same ExpenseId (different value of columns and DateCreated). Now I want to select all resent expenses. Resent exepense I mean if there is one or several EditedExpnes for an Expense you select the recent  EditedExpense otherwise the orginal Expense.
Espense Table:

```
ExpenseId, DateCreated, .... ReceiptFilePath
```

and EditedExpense table:

```
EditedExpenseId, ExpenseId, DateCreated, .... ReceiptFilePath
```

Comment: Some sample data would help us here.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT e.ExpenseId, e.DateCreated, e....., e.ReceiptFilePath,
    X.EditedExpenseId AS EditedExpenseId_, X.ExpenseId AS ExpenseId_, X.DateCreated AS DateCreated_, 
    X..... AS .....,  X.ReceiptFilePath AS ReceiptFilePath_
FROM Espense AS e
    OUTER APPLY
    (SELECT TOP 1 ee.EditedExpenseId, ee.ExpenseId, ee.DateCreated, ee.....,  ee.ReceiptFilePath
        FROM EditedExpense AS ee
        WHERE ee.ExpenseId = e.ExpenseId
        ORDER BY ee.DateCreated DESC, ee.EditedExpenseId DESC) AS X
```

Comment: It returns more than what I want, in c# code I  have to check for example if DateCreated_ not null use it otherwise use DateCreated for all columns and all resulted posts.

Comment: @user217648 you can add condition in the query itself as per your requirement